# Programmable Answering Machine Software?

Tags: windows, modem

Are there any free or commercial answering machine software that can be programmed to play different message based on the datetime of call?

hardware: TAPI voice modem on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think may be what you need:

[Kphonecenter](http://kphonecenter.sourceforge.net/):

> This is an application inspired by
>   Rapidcom Voice for Windows. It is an
>   app that lets you use a voice modem as
>   an answering machine,and a Fax. I also
>   plan to let it act as a dialup shell
>   account.
>
> The reason I started this project is
>   because
>
> 1: I hated running Window$,
>   and wanted to move off of it. 2: I
>   wanted something that was a little
>   more flexable and feature rich.
>   Something that could grow to meet
>   anyone's needs. So I started this
>   project. I visioned it running on some
>   sort of embedded device on the wall in
>   your house someday. Walk in, tap the
>   screen, listen to your messages. Even
>   talk on the phone while cooking Ziti
>   (Yes, I'm part Italian)

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

[IVAM2 0.3](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ivam2/):

ivam2 is an automatic phone answering machine software for ISDN and Linux. It is the completely rewritten successor of ivam featuring many additions.

ivam2 is seperated in two parts: the core daemon written in C and the automate logic coded in Python. The latter is pluggable and may be replaced by different implementations on a per phone number basis (both caller and callee). This makes ivam2 a very powerful application server for telephony services. The software is very scalable, multiple ISDN channels may be controlled from a single daemon. To write telephony applications for ivam2 is not complicated. In fact, they are simple executables which read audio data of the caller from STDIN and write audio data for the caller to STDOUT. DTMF sequences may be read from a FIFO special file. A framework for writing telephony applications in Python is provided, a simple answering machine script based on this framework as well. You are free to write applications in other languages such as Perl or C.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is capable of doing it:

http://www.asteriskwin32.com/

It is opensource.   I have not used the windows version.

I looked into the Linux version before for a VOIP project.

The Linux package has a lot of "features" - which also means not trivial to understand or setup.

Comment: this seems rather... complex for small business with only 1 TAPI voice modem...